# Can you use a UK paper license counterpart in New Zealand?

Tags: legal, uk, driving-licenses, new-zealand

A few weeks ago I lost my card UK driver's license somewhere in Arizona/Nevada.

Next month I will be in New Zealand.  My new license may not make it here in time.

However I still have the paper counterpart of my UK license.

I've been told you can drive/rent cars with the paper part + passport? Is this accurate, or do I need something additional to **be legal to drive**?

Comment: Can you not just use your old kiwi driving license when you're back "home", and not worry about your half lost UK one?

Comment: @Gagravarr - nope, we have to hand in our NZ licenses to get a UK one.  To get another NZ one I'd have to either turn in a UK one, or sit the driving test again. :/

Comment: How pesky. Many countries let you keep your "home" driving license when you get one of theirs, I didn't realise the UK didn't as I've always been starting *from* a UK license...

Comment: Yeah. Some used to then get back to NZ and just claim they "lost" their NZ one, but now the UK actually alerts NZ that you've converted, so even that loophole is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Hertz](http://hertz.co.nz) NZ

> At time of rental, the renter must present a full valid driver’s
>   licence issued from their country of residence that has been held for
>   a minimum of one year. If the licence is not in English, then an
>   International Driver’s Licence is also required.
>
> New Zealand law requires you to carry your driver’s licence with you whenever you are
>   driving.
>
> Renters from China can use a China Notarial Certificate
>   (CNC) which is used in place of an International Driving Permit,
>   however their original Chinese licence MUST accompany the driver as
>   well as the CNC.

Sadly the page was dynamic but i found the information through the following method:

Reservations -> Qualifications & Requirements -> EnterAiportCode:"AKL" -> ChoseTopic:"Drivers Liscence" -> Go

[NZTA](http://www.nzta.govt.nz/resources/factsheets/56/new-residents-and-visitors-driving-in-new-zealand.html) (New Zealand Transport Association)

> *A current and valid overseas driver licence means that your licence allows you to legally drive in your own country. If you are
>   disqualified from driving or your licence is currently suspended,
>   expired or revoked, then you are not allowed to drive in New Zealand.)

The Keyword there is "valid" my understanding is it is not a valid licence without both parts. However find information from the DVLA on this matter is tricky.

The [New Zealand Police](https://www.police.govt.nz/faq/items/23169) has the same statement as both the NZTA and Hertz.

Comment: Yeah the "validity" is tricky - in the US, they'll recognise the paper form + a passport.

Comment: yeah i noticed that but left it off the main answer because it was covered in the US question.