# Driving in the US but lost UK paper licence

Tags: usa, driving, uk-citizens, driving-licenses

I am in Florida, USA.  I cannot find my card UK licence, but have the separate paper part to the licence. Is it OK to drive with just the paper part?

Comment: The question is whether a Florida police officer would recognize the paper part as a license.  You have a license so could prove that in the long run, but the short time hassle is hard to say since I am not sure what the "paper part" looks like

Comment: If by "paper part" you are referring to an IDP, the answer is no-- it must be accompanied by the actual license and confers no privileges on its own.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I personally wouldn't risk it. In the UK, you have to show both parts of your driving license to the police, so I don't think it would be ok to just rely on the paper part in the US. When I drove in the US, I took the card and paper part, plus the IDP.

Comment: Related:[Can you use a UK paper license counterpart in New Zealand?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9788/can-you-use-a-uk-paper-license-counterpart-in-new-zealand)

Answer (score 3):

From [USCarHire.com](http://www.uscarhire.com/faq-licenses.aspx):

> The new style UK driving licence consists of two parts - a photo card
>   and a paper licence. The licence is not complete without BOTH parts.
>   You are advised to take both parts when collecting your vehicle as you
>   may be asked for them both.
>
> Often the rental company will only ask to see the photo part, so in
>   most cases you will be OK to drive, but in the event they do ask for
>   the paper part (which lists any points and endorsements) and you don't
>   have it with you, then you will not be allowed to drive, nor will you
>   then be entitled to a refund on your rental.
>
> If you do not have the paper part and the rental company do not ask
>   for it, so you collect your car, then you also run the risk of
>   problems in the event you are pulled over by Highway Patrol and asked
>   to show your license, as they may insist on seeing both parts. As it
>   is a legal requirement to carry your FULL license with you in the car
>   at all times when driving, then you could face legal consequences.

So you do in fact (probably) need both parts of your license, unless you literally 'get away' with it. However, if you're in an accident or similar, you're going to be in some serious trouble.

Comment: It's going to be interesting how awkward things are going to be for a while once the UK paper counterpart is no longer issued: https://www.gov.uk/government/news/driving-licence-changes